# sorting a linkedlist using quick sort in C

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

I am using linux and trying to write the program in C for sorting linked list elements using quick sort. here is my code.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
    struct node *plink;
};

struct node *first=NULL, *last=NULL;

void swap(struct node* a, struct node* b) {
    int temp;
    temp = a->data;
    a->data = b->data;
    b->data = temp;
}

void qsort(struct node *low, struct node *high) {
    if(low==NULL || high==NULL || low == high || low->plink == high)
        return ;

    struct node *pivot=low, *tmp=low->link;

    while(tmp != high->link) {
        if(tmp->data < low->data) {
            swap(pivot->link, tmp);
            pivot = pivot->link;
        }
        tmp = tmp->link;
    }

    swap(low, pivot);
    qsort(low, pivot->plink);
    qsort(pivot->link, high);
}
```

It's working fine for a small text file but not working for a file of 1.7M. Please tell me what I need to add.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Quick sort is more tailored to sorting arrays. For linked list, merge sort is much easier.

Comment: You are not showing the part related to the FILE you are using. What do you mean by "not working" ? It is normal that you program runs faster on small text than on big files...

Comment: @Coconop Data is getting inserted in the linked list. I have checked it by writing a display function. and "not working" means not giving any response. If you want to see my code for the insertion function which is used to take data from a text file and insert into the linked list, I can show you. Do I need to show now, if you want?

Comment: @hivert, does merge sort work with file of any size??

Comment: Did you insert some traces to see where it is stuck ? My guess is that your program is running but considering the size of the data to process it might take a while.

Comment: @user2892731 : Of course.

Comment: @Coconop yeah..!! It is working. I have checked it. but taking even so much time than I expected.  Thanks

Comment: You use a lot of stack space to call recursively. Stack has gone missing, perhaps.